# prefix Phone field, different Objects

Tags: apex, sobject, bestpractice

I have a method in beforeInsert trigger, when new SObject is inserted it should add a numeric prefix. That alone is working, but my assignment now is make it much shorter.
Currently I'm having 1 block of code for each sobject.

```
public static  void addPhonePrefix(List<SObject> sObjectsList){
            if (sObjectsList.get(0)instanceof Account) {
                for (SObject sobj : sObjectsList) {
                    Account account  = (Account)sobj;
                    //e.g. account.Phone = '+421'+account.Phone;
                    //CONDITIONS ... }
            }
            if (sObjectsList.get(0)instanceof Contact) {
                for (SObject sobj : sObjectsList) {
                    Contact contact  = (Contact)sobj;
                    //CONDITIONS ... }
            }
            if (sObjectsList.get(0)instanceof Lead) {
                for (SObject sobj : sObjectsList) {
                    Lead lead  = (Lead)sobj;
                    //CONDITIONS ... }
            }
}
```

Is there a way to use 1 block of code (conditions) for 3 sobjects (Leads, Contacts, Accounts) at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where [Dynamic Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic.htm) shines. You can write code just like this:

```
Map<sObjectType, sObjectField[]> fieldMap = new Map<sObjectType, sObjectField[]> {
    Account.sObjectType => new List<sObjectField> { Account.Phone },
    Contact.sObjectType => new List<sObjectField> { Contact.Phone },
    Lead.sObjectType => new List<sObjectField> { Lead.Phone }
};
public static void addPhonePrefix(sObject[] records) {
    for(sObject record: records) {
        for(sObjectField field: fieldMap.get(record.getSobjectType())) {
            String phone = (String)record.get(field);
            // conditions
        }
    }
}
```

The first part describes the fields you want to handle, and the method itself just uses those dynamic values to process data. You could further add a describe method that finds phone fields dynamically, but this would have serious CPU implications. This code is probably close to the optimal version you could ask for, a fair balance between CPU time and code size.

P.S. You could also have used switch statements to avoid the extra condition checks:

```
for(sObject record: sObjectsList) {
  switch on (record) {
    when Account accountRecord {
      String phone = accountRecord.Phone;
      // conditions
    }
    when Contact contactRecord {
      String phone = contactRecord.Phone;
      // conditions
    }
    when Lead leadRecord {
      String phone = contactRecord.Phone;
      // conditions
    }
  }
}
```

Though this is still longer than Dynamic Apex in most cases.

Comment: Its working on 'phone' but not on the actual 'record.get(field)'.... 
How can I cast that updated phone number back into the field?

Comment: @jur1s77 Use `record.put(field, newValue)`.